# How to create new row to ensure time series length is equal?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to perform to classify effectiveness of a treatment. Each of the id should contain 4 timeframes.

```
Dataframe
```

| id | timeframe | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1.2 |
| 1 | 4 | 1.1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1.1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1.1 |

The question is for example id 2 timeframe #3 is missing. How to create a new row added in the missing timeframe with the average distance value for all the rows with such issue?

I am getting the 'not all time is the same length' when running - Longitudinal clustering using "longitudinal k-means (KML)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `complete` to create the missing combination and then replace the `NA` with the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    complete(id, timeframe) %>%
    mutate(distance = replace(distance, is.na(distance) & is.na(rn), 
          mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

If the `mean` should be calculated within each 'id', then do a `group_by` before the `mutate`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    complete(id, timeframe) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(distance = replace(distance, is.na(distance) & is.na(rn), 
          mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: Thansk for idea, but how about add in a row with timeframe #3 as well?

Comment: @user9510596 you can add the row as well, but wouldn't that be more manual than `complete` i.e complete will automatically check whether any of the timeframe values are absent for a particular id

Comment: i have tried the suggested method. It will replace the row with mean if there is NA in value. However, in my case the entire row of timeframe #3 is not there in the dataframe, so it will not be treated as NA.

Comment: @user9510596 not clear based on your comment.  what I understand is some combinations are missing and you want to add those combinations and then replace the 'distnace only for that rows with mean value

Comment: @user9510596 are you saying that there are other rows already havng NA values and you don't want to replace those NA with mean?

Comment: @user9510596 I updated the post.  I am not really sure whether you meant not to change NA in other rows or not.  The fix should only changes the `NA` in those missing combinations

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I have tried the solution but strangely the missing combination just never shown.

Comment: @user9510596 can you update your post with another example and expected output as this exxample works fine with the code though

Comment: @user9510596 There is one possiblity that it may not have showed i.e. if your data is already grouped, you may need `df1 %>% ungroup %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    complete(id, timeframe)`

Comment: Yes, it finally works, as what u have mentioned it has to ungroup first before mutate

Comment: @user9510596 it is possible that you may have used `group_by` in your other steps and unless the grouping is removed, it stays and causes this issues when you use complete etc